# How to send headers from YQL in order to return JSON format when querying opendatabc API?

Tags: json, curl, yql

I'm wondering if there is a way to send headers from YQL (or the YQL console) like there is in cURL.

I would like to return JSON by specifying the header `Accept: application/json`.

I am able to return JSON in with cURL and the command line like this:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' http://www.opendatabc.ca/data?=births
```

but I can't figure out how to set the header when sending YQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [YQL Open Data Tables](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_dev_guide.html).

[Here is](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=USE%20%27https%3A//gist.github.com/raw/2042904/cd8ee40b01c9cc96fbc259b752d4c5e20030702a/gistfile1.txt%27%20AS%20remote%3B%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20remote%20WHERE%20url%3D%27http%3A//graph.facebook.com/%3Fid%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F%27) a simple demonstration.

You can find the gist for the example Open Data Table XML file here: https://gist.github.com/2042904 *(Check out the documentation [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=USE%20%27https://gist.github.com/raw/2042904/cd8ee40b01c9cc96fbc259b752d4c5e20030702a/gistfile1.txt%27%20AS%20remote;%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20remote%20WHERE%20url=%27http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F%27).)*

You will notice in my example XML that I'm using **y.xmlToJson** on the **response** object received from the **get()** request. This is because YQL converts JSON taken from web services into E4X. More about that in [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706643/yql-odt-rest-get-response-exists-but-inaccessible).

Comment: I accept your answer and your example does work but using the URL in my example still returns results=null... In YQL console I do: USE 'https://gist.github.com/raw/2042904/cd8ee40b01c9cc96fbc259b752d4c5e20030702a/gistfile1.txt' AS remote; SELECT * FROM remote WHERE url='http://www.opendatabc.ca/data?=birthshttp://www.opendatabc.ca/data?=births' but it returns an error. Perhaps there is an issue with the server in question. Thanks for your answer though, you did do it :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your url. I've tried to [fix the issue](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?jsonCompat=new#h=USE%20%27https%3A//gist.github.com/raw/2042904/1d3170ecf1b1f33f219cbaa48d056c45cdeb3a98/gistfile1.txt%27%20AS%20remote%3B%20SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20remote%20WHERE%20url%3D%27http%3A//www.opendatabc.ca/data%3F%3Dbirths%27%3B), but the YQL server has JSON parsing issues. I've tried to alleviate that problem in a few ways but was unable to find a good solution. The query does work now and I would recommend that you parse the JSON client-side.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank YOU! That's just great :) -- yes, I can parse the JSON client side. Yaaaay!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `format` parameter when querying YQL over API, instead of headers. Either by `format=json` or `format=xml`.

JSON example:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "example.com"' http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json
```

XML example:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode 'q=SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = "example.com"' http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=xml
```

Answer (score 0):

use "jq", if have not installed it yet, run this command first
`sudo apt-get install jq`

then you can curl your url like this

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' http://www.opendatabc.ca/data?=births | jq '.'
```

Comment: I was asking how to send headers from YQL, not curl.