# YQL ODT - REST GET response exists but inaccessible

Tags: javascript, yql

I am writing an [Open Data Table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html) to aggregate like counts from various social networking services.

My attempt can be found [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=USE%20%27http%3A//files.swook.net/socialcount.xml%27%20AS%20remote%3B%20SELECT%20%2a%20from%20remote%20WHERE%20url%3D%27http%3A//www.yahoo.com/%27) at the YQL console, with the Open Data Table XML being [here](http://files.swook.net/socialcount.xml).

My current problem - as you will find out on trying my query - is that Twitter and Facebook's requests return an empty *response* object with:

> org.mozilla.javascript.UniqueTag@399a063e: NOT_FOUND

instead of populating it with the JSON that each respective service returns.

I think that the non-zero *content-length* header returned in the *rest* object indicates that the YQL server has received the correct JSON reply, and thus the problem isn't on the web services' sides but on either YQL's or my ODT's side.

I have tried to solve this problem in various ways and have been unsuccessful. Could some YQL experts please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: I have found a workaround and will post it below when StackOverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution and this may be a bug in the YQL server.

What happens is that when a web service returns content with *content-type* 'application/json', YQL parses it into the [*E4X* format](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-bestpractices.html#yql-execute-e4x), an xml representation for JavaScript. Why it does so, I do not have any clue on since JSON should be parsed into a JavaScript object.

The problem with this *E4X* format seems to be that it is only accessible within the optional callback function that can be supplied when calling **y.rest()**.

When trying to store bits of data into a variable, and apply it to the *response.object* object, I found that the console would return a NOT FOUND error. This means that what I thought I had stored into my variables was not a string or integer value for these social button counts, but a reference to an E4X node.

To solve this problem, I performed **parseInt** magic on the node to get my numbers.

I believe this behaviour is very odd and is most likely an unintended bug. Hopefully, a developer will pick up on this issue to prevent future confusions.